# airflow on docker FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: docker, airflow

[airflow error log]
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/kim/airflow_demo/data/s3_data.json'
[2023-11-16, 10:17:54 KST] {taskinstance.py:1420} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=upload_S3, task_id=upload, execution_date=20231116T011751, start_date=20231116T011753, end_date=20231116T011754
[2023-11-16, 10:17:54 KST] {standard_task_runner.py:97} ERROR - Failed to execute job 1086 for task upload ([Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/kim/airflow_demo/data/s3_data.json'; 335)
[2023-11-16, 10:17:54 KST] {local_task_job.py:156} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-11-16, 10:17:54 KST] {local_task_job.py:273} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check

[docker yaml file]
volumes:
- ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
- ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
- ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
- ./data:/opt/airflow/data

[local]
(base) [root@localhost airflow_demo]# ls -l
합계 20
-rw-r--r--  1 root    root  136 11월  1 11:05 Dockerfile
drwxr-xr-x  2 root    root    6 10월 26 10:21 config
drwxr-xr-x  6   50000 root  213 11월 16 09:48 dags
drwxrwxrwx  2   50000 root   26 11월 16 09:02 data

[docker container]
airflow@37dd707bf5a6:/opt/airflow$ ls
airflow.cfg  dags  logs  plugins  webserver_config.py

I don't know what's wrong

1. checked the path
2. authorized

Any help would be so appreciated

1. checked the path
2. authorize